# Error trying to move email from inbox to subfolder

Tags: vbscript, outlook

I need to write VBS to move specific emails from an inbox to a subfolder. I am quite new to VBS, I have the following code:

```
Set outobj = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set myNamespace = outobj.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Inbox = myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set Items = Inbox.Items
Dim lngCount
For lngCount = Items.Count To 1 Step -1
  Set Item = Items(lngCount)
  If Item.Class = olMail Then
    If Item.SenderName = "Mail Delivery System" Then
     Set SubFolder = Inbox.Folders("CBIR")
     Item.Move SubFolder
    End If
  End If
Next
```

When I run this I get an error saying:

> C:\Users\dmurphy54\AppData\Local\Temp\WinAutomation\jp0f1kguwqq.tmp(3, 1) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Invalid procedure call or argument: 'myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder'

Does anybody know how I can fix this?

Comment: Same applies [How to use excel built-in constant in VBS](//stackoverflow.com/a/39956808) but you need the `olFolderInbox` value from the Outlook Type Library.

Answer (score -2):

Solved this one myself. Needed the following line:

```
Const olFolderInbox = 6
```

Comment: Solved it [yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52776706/error-trying-to-move-email-from-inbox-to-subfolder#comment92485123_52776706)?